# navigator.camera.getPicture not working properly

Tags: android, cordova, camera, samsung-mobile, cordova-plugins

In my cordova(v3.3) single page application  use the following code to get the camera image

```
function takeSkiImage(){
   capturePhoto();
}  

function capturePhoto() {
// Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
    alert((navigator.camera.getPicture));
    navigator.camera.cleanup(); 
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, function fail(error){
       alert("failed : " + error.code);
    }, {
      quality : 90,
      targetWidth : 2300,
      targetHeight : 1800,
      destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
  });
}


function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageURI) {
    var gotFileEntry = function(fileEntry) {
    alert("got image file entry: " + fileEntry.fullPath);
    var gotFileSystem = function(fileSystem) {

        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("sample", {
            create : true
        }, function(dataDir) {
            var d = new Date();
            var n = d.getTime();
            var newFileName = n + ".jpg";
            alert("File Downloaded");
            // copy the file
            fileEntry.moveTo(dataDir, newFileName, null, fsFail);

        }, dirFail);

    };
    // get file system to copy or move image file to
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            gotFileSystem, fsFail);
};
// resolve file system for image
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, gotFileEntry, fsFail);

// file system fail
var fsFail = function(error) {
    alert("failed with error code: " + error.code);

};

var dirFail = function(error) {
    alert("Directory error code: " + error.code);

};
}
```

The above code working fine in **NEXUS 7(v 4.2) device and alerts the camera start** but in **samsung tab 4(v 4.4) devices the alert camera start never fires first time** but it `goes to camera and able to take picture but not able to save.`

when again take the new image at the time only the old image get stored. like wise take new image only the previous image stored. How to solve this. Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: Can you try with  Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL and see the results on both devices?

Comment: @AAhad tried same behaviour..

Comment: Hmm, before attempting to open camera , call this to clear cache. navigator.camera.cleanup(); it might help

Comment: @AAhad used this also navigator.camera.cleanup(); nothing changed..i want to store the image taken from camera in particular folder can you tell me how to do this.

Comment: @AAhad updated the post please see it..

Comment: looks mistakes in code, let me try in my local project and will update you

Comment: @AAhad ok please update the errors.i will..

Answer (score 0):

To save an image you need to configure options properly.

```
function takeSkiImage(){
   alert("hi");
   navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageData) {
      alert("camera start");
   }, onFail, {
    quality : 100, allowEdit : true,
    targetWidth: 2350,
    targetHeight: 1800,
    destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    saveToPhotoAlbum : true
   });
}
```

The `saveToPhotoAlbum : true` is required to **save** image.

**Update:**

To save file in a custom location, you have to use [File plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md).

Comment: Then you have to use another File plugin

Comment: i use like this `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, gotFileEntry, fsFail);` but the problem is it never goes inside getPicture

Comment: Please update your code accordingly, let me see how you are calling window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, gotFileEntry, fsFail); to getPicture

Comment: but the same code works well in nexus 7 device and store file in custom location.